# Paint the rectangle with least movement

Tags: calculation-puzzle, geometry

There is a painting brush tool that can paint a circle area of $1$ unit radius. What is the shortest paint track for painting at least a $100*100$ units rectangle area on wall? How much did the brush moved in total?

---

Rules:

- Brush must touch wall only *once*. (It says that painting should be continues and you have only one shot)
- Painting can start and finish anywhere.
- Painting outside the rectangle does not matter. (Actually it is inevitable to paint some of the outer area of rectangle)

---

**Example:**

> Here's a naive try for a $10*10$ rectangle and the same brush with radius of $1$ unit
>
>  [image]
>  
>  result is $58$ units for $10*10$ rectangle and $(n*m)+2m-2$ for $n*2m$ rectangle

Comment: Do you need to 'fill' the 4 corners aswell? Round things don't tend to fill rectangles unless you go outside the borders..

Comment: @TimCouwelier, painting outside the rectangle does not matter. (It is inevitable to paint some of outer area). Thanks

Comment: Silly me initially started with a spiral, untill i realised all the small corner sections it left undone...
added an answer, but I'm not sure I can prove it's optimal.

Comment: Quick heads up as to why I deleted my post: length of a diagonal was not sqrt(2)/2 x side but sqrt(2) x side, which ruined the calculations.. alot.

Comment: **please** provide further hints! does it paint continously or does it paint seperate filled circles?

Comment: @MartinFrank, It's now described in question! thanks for asking

Comment: I don't get it, why would any solution be better than the trivial snake solution that Elgert mentioned? It seems like the length of the path is just a function of how much paint you use, so any solution which minimizes wasted paint works

Comment: @BenAaronson The snake solution wastes quite a lot of paint, actually, from painting outside the rectangle and from sharp turns.

Comment: @Moyli, Exactly! I think Tim thought about sharp tuens that tried to find a spiral path

Comment: @Moyli: I think a snake-ish solution is optimal, provided that one "flares" each end of the zig-zag and handles specially the start and end, as well as the first return after the start, and the last departure before the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best I can do (so far) is a total track length of 5083.592 (see below).

**Update:** You can also do away with the final returning curved path in my final solution, which chops off pi/4, so the total length is reduced to 5082.807

[image]

Comment: Nicely done! best answer for now... but how did you calculate that number?

Comment: Is it better to do this spiral path instead of going back and forth?

Comment: Why do you use circular curves of radius one?  I would think the two constraints on the path are that it reach the outside corner, and that it reach the vertical/horizontal lines soon enough to avoid leaving gaps at the inside corner.  I would think replacing the two curves with straight (but angled) segments would reduce the required distance.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that approach should improve the optimal distance to about 5064.3--a noticeable improvement.

Comment: Yes, you might be right. A while after I made my edit i had the feeling that I got it a bit wrong, but haven't got back to update it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you better visualize it

[image: I hi]

Comment: How are you going to fill the gaps shown in this picture: http://i.imgur.com/6OFDVuo.png

Comment: wow great - i think thats better than the old 'written' answer! i thought about your path and i find it more and more attractive! (i'll have to check length and compare again, but i like it!!)

Comment: @Moyli that was the same what i was thinking!! but honestly i really like this picture as a base of conversation!

Comment: @Moyli Just move the paint brush up until the gap is gone, then again repeat the diagonal movement inwards

Comment: I thought about that. The only problem this method has is that if you start with a diagonal move second line will not cover that easily.

Comment: @Moyli on each iteration you just make a diagonal move to paint those gaps or another idea is to first paint all the corners and sides of the square then continue with an inside square spiral until you go to the center

Comment: So if you were to actually answer the question (what is the shortest path & how long is it), which one of those is shorter and how long is it? Can you prove it's the shortest possible?

Answer (score 1):

A solution much better than Penguino's "spiral" can be achieved by starting with Penguino's zig-zag (the one with length 5098) but adjusting it slightly.  Looking at the first place the line comes toward the left from the right, it extends all the way to (0,3) and then (0,5) for the purpose of being within one unit of (0,2) and (0,6), but for any x and y in the range (0,1) such that x²+y²≤1, those points could be reached by having the line extend to (1+x,1), (x,2+y), (x,6-y), and (1+x,5) before returning to the right.  Penguino's zig-zag is a special case for x=0,y=1 but x=0.6 y=0.8 yields a much better result (assuming the right side is treated similarly, it will reduce the amount of x excursion per row by 1.2, but adds only 0.8 worth of y excursion, with about half of that being on shallow diagonals).  The net effect is a total length under 5060.5--a noticeable savings.

The slight tweak used for the above number entails starting at (x,2-y), then moving to (x,y), and going to (1+x,1) and all subsequent points in normal fashion.  Note that things must be drawn in that order to avoid leaving an unpainted area on the top.  Note also that using slightly different coordinates could improve things a bit, but further improvements are apt to be fairly slight.

Answer (score -1):

if you draw a circle you will be **NEVER** able to fill the rectangle...

if you **FILL** circles you might need w/2 x h/2 filled circles (even filled circles) on the first run and then need (w-1)/2 x (h-1)/2 filled circles (odd filled circles) to fill the gaps between... you can 'cut' pathes when you draw a *even* line and then switch to an *odd* line...

lenght of even line = 100;
length of odd line = 99;
path to switch from odd to even (and back) = Math.Squrt(2) (i'll say it's 1.4 for terms of easier use)...

so you have 100 x 100 + 99 x 99 + 99*1.4 = 
            10'000    + 9801    + 138.6  = 19939.6 (having rounding erros)

[image]

```
BLACK  = even circles
RED    = odd circles
PURPLE = rectangle
GREEN  = path
```

i **can't proof** that this path would be shorter:

[image]

### update:

ok ok, after learning that that paint tool sprays continously i show another path...

[image]

Draw a cross (starts NorthWest -> SouthEast -> SouthWest -> NorthEast) on step back and then make the loop into the center

Comment: The question says "circle area," not circle. Elgert's solution is 50 x 100 + 49 x 2 = 5098 so almost 4 times shorter.

Comment: you describe the amount of circled areas - noth the length of the path...

Comment: Ok, I think the confusion here is about how the painting tool works. My understanding is that it paints continuously, like a paint brush, not like a stamp that makes individual circles.

Comment: ok ok - that clears out much of my misunderstandig!! i didn't know it was painting **continually**

Comment: ?does? it paint continously? or does it paint only one filled circle at a time? who can answer this?

Comment: I'm going to edit the question to clarify about continuity painting.

Comment: grml - i put so much effort into this hahahaa.... ok ok, thanks for clearing **THAT** out ^^$

Comment: My bad! It should be better if I think that before writing question. Also English is not my mother language :-)

Comment: same here same here *damn english* haha =) sorry, no cursing please! again your adjustment lead to another solution then... ^^ keep up the good riddlges!

Comment: Don't think the spiral answer works either. Assume the first three lengths to be 98 98 98, then you'll 'bump into' the lines you already had and the next series will be 96 96 96, then 94 94 94 etc etc. In total you'll end up with 3 times the sum of (2;4;6;..;90;92;94;96;98), or 7350, plus the length of the cross, which undoubtedly puts you over the previously mentioned value of 5098.

Comment: yes, very right you are - but i'm still doubtful on how where this '5098' path lenght emerges from... can you show me again how/where that path is calculated?

Comment: It's in my first comment. If you go up and down (or left to right), you need to do so 50 times to cover the entire square (width of the brush is 2). 50 x 100 is 5000, plus 49 two-unit moves you need to make the transition to the next section: 2 x 49 = 98, plus the up-down paths = 5098. You can make the transitions at a slight angle so the actual number is a bit lower.

Comment: @Moyli - the 5098 bit i agree on, not on the slight angle. The center of the brush needs to be on the outer edge for it to work without the bands overlapping. Shortest way to achieve this on consecutive bands is the straight line.

Comment: You're right, didn't think that far.

Comment: @TimCouwelier you do a little mistake! it will be 98, 98, 98 **94, 94, 94, 90, 90, 90** and so on - i haven't had the time to calculate but i'll do it tomorrow or so ^^ maybe you can help out?

Comment: @Martin Frank:
Don't think I made a mistake there in how the steps evolve Try drawing it. First step is move from (1,99) to (99,99), then down to (99,1), left to (1,1), and then up to (1,97), right to (97,97), etc etc.

Comment: when you draw a vertical line on the left with radius 1 (diameter=2) and you draw another vertical line on the right (again with radius 1 -> diameter 2) the remaining difference will be .... 96!!! so again, lets draw two more vertical lines (each 2 in diameter), remaining difference will be 92...

Comment: You're both wrong, actually. It's 98, 98, 98, 96, 96, 94, 94, ... to a total of 4998 (plus or minus a couple units -- I can't tell off the top of my head how the spiral ends.) You can see the idea in this 10x10 square where the pattern is 8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 4, 4, 2, 2: http://i.imgur.com/ISBhYOw.png

Comment: Ah, good catch. Somehow it didn't make sense I ended up that high, given not that much paint was wasted. Got the general idea right, but failed to notice you only get each length twice after the initial loop.

Comment: same here, same here - honestly i haven't made **any** effort in doing **any** math so far, but i know i should ^^