# Paint the Rectangle with least number of Circular Stamp Touches

Tags: geometry

What is the minimum number of touches for painting at least a $100*100$ rectangle if you have one circular stamp tool that paints a circular area of $1$ unit radius in every touch?

This question is very similar to [Paint the rectangle with least movement](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2605/paint-the-rectangle-with-least-movement). But this time there is no brush tool for painting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you array circles with radius = 1 on a triangular as shown below, you can cover a rectangular area with

```
 height = (3n-1)/2, where n is the number of rows of circles, and

 width = sqrt(3)(2m-1)/2, if each row is of length m, or
 width = sqrt(3)(m-1), if alternate rows are of length m, and m-1
```

So you can cover a 100x100 square with 67 rows, of alternating length 59,58,59...(actual rectangular area covered is 100 high by ~100.459 wide).

Total number of circles used is 34x59 + 33*58 = 3920

[image]

Comment: that totally sounds reasonable!!

Comment: If you start with a 58-row, the total number of circles used would be 34x58 + 33x59 = 3919.

Answer (score 1):

you might need w/2 x h/2 filled circles (even filled circles) on the first run and then need (w-1)/2 x (h-1)/2 filled circles (odd filled circles) to fill the gaps between... you can 'cut' pathes when you draw a *even* line and then switch to an *odd* line...

lenght of even line = 100; length of odd line = 99; path to switch from odd to even (and back) = Math.Squrt(2) (i'll say it's 1.4 for terms of easier use)...

so you have 100 x 100 + 99 x 99 + 99*1.4 = 10'000 + 9801 + 138.6 = 19939.6 (having rounding erros)

[image]

```
BLACK  = even circles
RED    = odd circles
PURPLE = rectangle
GREEN  = path
```

i **can't proof** that this path would be shorter:

[image]

Comment: your second path (or solution) was shorter. but the question still stays unanswered, "what is the minimum number?"

Comment: I have [somehow] copied your answer up here

Comment: wow thank you @Rafe - i hope this will be a good start for discussion whereas i must confess the solution from penguino looks very nice as well...

Comment: There's no "paths" involved here, just numbers of circles. The second half of the first picture and the second picture can be removed, and as Rafe mentioned, there is no circle count.